# Error: user not authorized to perform: iam:GetInstanceProfile

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce

When trying to create "Interactive Cluster" using ,

> ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --name "Interactive Cluster"
>   --num-instances=1 --master-instance-type=m1.large --hive-interactive

I get the following message printed on the screen:

```
Error: <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://iam.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-05-08/">
<Error>
<Type>Sender</Type>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>User: arn:aws:iam::747358775237:user/zohaan is not authorized to perform: 
   iam:GetInstanceProfile on resource: instance profile MyCustomRole</Message>
</Error>
<RequestId>2b8ada42-6a68-11e3-b613-33fa84edb9a5</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
./aws/core/client.rb:318:in `return_or_raise'
./aws/core/client.rb:419:in `client_request'
(eval):3:in `get_instance_profile'
./commands.rb:1200:in `role_exists?'
./commands.rb:1252:in `validate_jobflow_role'
./commands.rb:1194:in `validate'
./commands.rb:43:in `validate'
./commands.rb:43:in `each'
./commands.rb:43:in `validate'
./commands.rb:2426:in `create_and_execute_commands'
./elastic-mapreduce-cli.rb:13
elastic-mapreduce:6:in `require'
elastic-mapreduce:6
```

Can anybody help on getting past the error?

I created MyCustomeRole as instructed:

```
    {
      "Statement": [
       {
         "Action": [
         "elasticmapreduce:*",
         "ec2:*",
         "cloudwatch:*",
         "s3:*",
         "sdb:*",
         "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
         "iam:PassRole",
         "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
         "iam:GetRole"
        ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "*"
        }
     ]
   }
```